# Как минифицировать js файл webpack в laravel?

Tags: laravel, webpack

вот конфиг вебпака

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

исходный файл через npm run production занимает около 1 мб,
можно как-то минифицировать файл?

PS: приложение на React-те

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы добиться максимальной оптимизации, нужно использовать кастомную конфигурацию, к тому же очень важно мигрировать проект на `webpack > 4`, там намного больше возможностей благодаря новой опции `optimization`, насколько я знаю `mix` предоставляет возможность задать свою конфигурацию:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const { cpus } = require('os');
const { join } = require('path');

mix.webpackConfig({
    context: __dirname,

    entry: {
        app: './resources/assets/js/app.js',
        vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', ...еще какие-то библиотеки, от которых зависит ваше приложение]
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: join(__dirname, 'public/js')
    },

    mode: 'production',

    target: 'web',

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js(x)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    },

    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                parallel: cpus().length,
                sourceMap: true,

                uglifyOptions: {
                    ecma: 8,
                    mangle: {
                        keep_classnames: true,
                        keep_fnames: true
                    },
                    keep_classnames: true,
                    keep_fnames: true,

                    compress: {
                        warnings: false,
                        drop_console: false,
                        keep_classnames: true,
                        ie8: false
                    },

                    output: {
                        beautify: false,
                        comments: false
                    }

                }
            })
        ],

        runtimeChunk: true,
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    name: 'vendor',
                    test: 'vendor',
                    enforce: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Используем агрессивное разбиение кода:

```
yarn add -D html-webpack-plugin@next
```

Добавим чуть-чуть опций в конфигурацию:

```
// webpack.config.js

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const AggressiveSplittingPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/AggressiveSplittingPlugin');

webpackConfig({
    ....,

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './path-to-index.php'
        }),

        new AggressiveSplittingPlugin({
            minSize: 30000,
            maxSize: 50000
        })
    ]
});
```

`AggressiveSplittingPlugin` разбивает каждый `chunk`, пока не достигнет указанного `maxSize`, в данном случае это 50 килобайт (50000 байт).

Используем ленивую загрузку везде, где это возможно:

```
yarn add -D babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

Не забываем про `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ....,
    "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

Теперь вам доступен динамический импорт `import` (синтаксический сахар поверх `Promise + require.ensure`). Используйте динамический импорт в тех случаях, где вам нужно использовать какую-то зависимость в определенном месте, например в приложении есть графики и мы хотим использовать `chart.js`, нам не нужно изначально запихивать эту библиотеку в наш бандл, достаточно в компоненте где она будет использоваться ее подгрузить на лету (`on demand`):

```
class Chart extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        if (typeof window.Chart === 'undefined') {
            await import('chart.js');
        }

        // работаем с Chart
        new Chart(ctx, ....);
    }
}
```

Comment: laravel-mix не работает с webpack 4

Comment: зачем тогда использовать `laravel-mix`? идите на компромисс - либо забудьте про минификацию и пользуйтесь `laravel-mix`, либо откажитесь от него и используйте кастомный `webpack`